# Redux warnings on unmounted React components overflow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I get this error when I run my ReactJs code:

index.js:1375 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

I tried the below code, but i still get the same error. I see code on stackoverflow with the API call in componentDidMount, but mine is coming from Redux. How do I unsubscribe or cancel subscriptions and async tasks in componentWillUnmount?

Been struggling with this all night long.

This is my Reducers:

```
const initState = {
 error_message: null,
 patient : null,
 isLoading: true,
 patients: [],
}

const patientReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type){
   case ALL_PATIENT_ERROR:
   case SHOW_PATIENT_ERROR:
    console.log(action.payload)
    return {
          ...state,
          error_message: action.payload
         }
   case SHOW_PATIENT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
       patient : action.payload.patient,
       isLoading: false
   }
   case ALL_PATIENT_SUCCESS:
     return {
      ...state,
      patients : action.payload,
      isLoading: false
     }
   default:
    return state
  }
}
```

Component:

```
class AllPatient extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  state ={
    isLoading: true
  }

 _changeHandler = (e) => {
  let data = {...this.state}
  data[e.target.name] = e.target.value
  this.setState(data)
  }

  componentDidMount = () =>{
    this._isMounted = true;
      this.props.getPatients()
  }

  componentWillUnmount = () =>{
    this._isMounted = false;
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

 render() {

  console.log(this.props)
  let {patients} = this.props.patients
  console.log(patients)


  return (
   <div>
    <Container>
     <SearchPatients change={this._changeHandler} />
     {(this.props.patients.isLoading) ? <Loading /> :
     <Card>
       <Card.Body>
       <Card.Title>
       All Patients
       </Card.Title>
       <Table responsive>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>DOB</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Last Visit</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {patients.patients.map(patient => 
            <PatientList key={patient._id} patient={patient}/>
          )}

        </tbody>
      </Table>
       </Card.Body>
     </Card>}
    </Container>
   </div>
  )
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
  console.log(state)
  return {
    patients : state.patients,//.patients.patients,
    // isLoading : state.isLoading
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
  return {
    getPatients : () => dispatch(getAllPatients())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AllPatient)
```

Action:

```
export const getAllPatients = () => async (dispatch) => {
 let token = getToken()
 if(token){
  try{
     const response = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/api/patients`,headerInfo,{cancelToken: source.token})

      return dispatch({
       type : ALL_PATIENT_SUCCESS,
       payload: response.data
      })

   }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
    return dispatch({
     type : ALL_PATIENT_ERROR,
     payload: e.response
    })
   }
 }else{
  console.log('error')
 }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Didi - why do you need _isMounted? what is it propose?

Comment: if you remove the setState in changeHandler, does the error still persists?

Comment: @Jank I was googling and saw that as a solution with isMounted but didnt make any difference,

Comment: @kkesley that isnt called at all only when i type in form fields

Comment: I just want to scratch out possibilities. Either way, can you try it and confirm if the error still persists?

Comment: @Didi - I'm asking because you are using this flag in `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` and potentially causing this error. Try to remove `componentWillUnmount` entirly and all _isMounted instances as they are redundant.

Comment: @jank it didnt change anything, actually it was the start of the problem

Comment: is there another hook i should use to dispatch my redux action?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cancel Redux Action after Unmount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57763245/cancel-redux-action-after-unmount)