# Cancel Redux Action after Unmount

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-lifecycle

I want to cancel some functions after component unmount because it causes memory leak my code looks like this

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.org.org !== this.props.org.org && this.mounted) {
      this.props.clearGraph();
      this.props.graphGet(this.props.org.org);
      this.setState({ org: this.props.org.org });
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      const abox = "a" + this.props.org.org.substr("1");
      this.props.getHistory(abox);
      this.props.graphGet(this.props.org.org);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
  }
```

all I want is to cancel graphGet which is a redux action

Comment: Why you need componentDidUpdate? Did you have store for state?
better you pull the state from the father and send it to the child component.
In redux you can use mapStateToProps to update a new state.
maybe is that the memory leak problem (componentDidUpdate)

Comment: I didn't understand u could u explain plz

Comment: it's not the problem I need to stop graphGet from fetching because I focre update in some cases in other component

Comment: Maybe `this.mounted = false;` in componentWillUnmount
see this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49906437/how-to-cancel-a-fetch-on-componentwillunmount)

Comment: if you want to cancel, consider using [`redux saga`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cancel Redux actions by design. Once they get dispatched, they are processed by reducers and the state transition is performed.

You can however dispatch another action to revert the state changes or causing side effects. Normally you would use another library like `redux-observable` for the latter.

You can for example define 3 actions: `START_GRAPH_GET`, `CANCEL_GRAPH_GET` and `FINISH_GRAPH_GET`. On `START` you start your fetch, on `CANCEL` you cancel any outstanding fetches and once a fetch completes you dispatch `FINISH` and keep the result in the store.

In order to render the results you would need to use `react-redux` connect with a `mapStateToProps` function.

To cancel on unmount, you would just dispatch an `CANCEL` action, if necessary.

Since your code does not show anything related to Redux at all, I think a more general answer is reasonable here.